# Importing project to eclipse IDE through shell script

Tags: java, eclipse, shell

I am working a project which consists of maven projects that includes subprojects. I am planning to write a shell script so that it will import all the projects into the eclipse workspace. Is it possible to import [not only for maven]projects through scripts? If yes, please tell me references or suggestions.

Any type of script[shell/dos/perl]. OS is windows/linux. i just want to know whether eclipse IDE supports or not. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What Script are you looking for? What OS are you using?

Comment: Any type of script[shell/dos/perl]. OS is windows/linux. i just want to know whether eclipse IDE supports or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should include this in your question to make it more clear for people who trying to help you.